# apache2 turn off all scripting in directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm working on a website which will allow users to upload their own content, they'll basically be given a directory and a lightweight file manager.

Besides extensions and size checks, which other measures should I use to protect the server from malicious uploads?

The first thing that comes into my mind is disable any kind of server scripting. How do I do it? I presume it will be a .htaccess in parent directory, but what should I put inside? I know that extension check is not really enough as a php code hidden inside a .jpg image will happily execute...

Also, preventing users from uploading .htaccess is obvious.

The server Linux running Apache2 with PHP. I do not have access to php.ini.

Comment: In your upload form you can control allowed file types. You can also use `chmod` to manage user directory permission and thus prevent them from executing anything, while still giving read and write access.

Comment: "php code hidden inside a .jpg image will happily execute" I'm not sure that's true unless you've specifically configured your web server to pass jpg files to the PHP engine.

Comment: If file extension check enough then? If I use `chmod()`.